# Grouping strings from a file

Tags: java

there is a text file, some code is stored there, how can I to group for example the whole **for loops**, or **if**, **while**, and then write them to the collection

For example there is a file that I read and wrote into an array:

```
0)Class A{
1)if(a>0){
2)a=a+1:
3)System.out.print(a);
4)}
5)if(a<0){
6)for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
7)words.add(s[i]);
8)}
9)for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
10)words.add(s[i]);
11)}
12)}
13)for(j=0; j<sap.length; j++){
14)Rep.add(s[i]);
15)System.out.println(s[i]);
16)}
17)for(j=0; j<sap.length; j++){
18)Rep.add(s[i]);
19)System.out.println(s[i]);
20)}
21)}
```

After regrouping, he should become this:

```
0)Class A{
1)if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
2)if(a<0){
3)for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
words.add(s[i]);
}
4)for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
words.add(s[i]);
}
}
5)for(j=0; j<sap.length; j++){
Rep.add(s[i]);
System.out.println(s[i]);
}
6)for(j=0; j<sap.length; j++){
Rep.add(s[i]);
System.out.println(s[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add to the question, I have no idea how to implement it, you can throw some  ideas

Comment: Your structure doesn't even make sense. You're trying to squeeze a tree into a list.

Comment: I need to create a tree as I understand it? @shmosel

Comment: Logically, that's how code blocks are organized.

Comment: In fact, I need this grouping so that later I can delete duplicates. This is my task, with my current knowledge in Java and in programming I cannot create such a tree, can you please suggest another solution to this problem? @shmosel

Comment: This is a site for asking and answering *specific* questions. Asking someone to fully code a solution to a vaguely-defined problem is way out of scope here, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Stack to balance braces. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZOLb0xHB_Q). Your situation is very similar, this should put you in the right direction.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is the actual implementation of Stack

Edit: Being downvoted? Please explain, this is the direction that should be taken unless someone else has a better idea.