# Do not delete duplicates on LinkedHashSet

Tags: java

I do not understand why duplicates are not deleted when adding to Set, I read from the file, there is some code that is grouped into Sheets

there was a file like this:

```
1)Class A{
2)if(a>0){
3)a=a+1:
4)System.out.print(a);
5)}
6)if(a>0){
7)a=a+1:
8)System.out.print(a);
9)}
10)}
```

then Became this:

```
0)Class A{
1)if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
2)if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
}
```

After which I add it to the LinkedHashSet and expect to remove a duplicate ie one if block, but nothing happens, why ??Please Explain

Here is my code:

```
class C {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String [] rows = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("\n");
        for ( String s : rows ){
            //System.out.println(s);
       }

        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<String> newLines = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line : rows) {
            if (line.endsWith("{")) {
                if (newLine.length() > 0) {
                    newLines.add(newLine.toString());
                }
                newLine = new StringBuilder(line);
            } else {
                newLine.append("\n").append(line);
            }

        }
        newLines.add(newLine.toString());
        String[] newstr = new String[newLines.size()];

        newLines.toArray(newstr);
        for(String b : newstr){
             System.out.println(b);
         }

         int i;
        LinkedHashSet<String> text = new  LinkedHashSet<>();
       for(i=0; i<newstr.length; i++){
            text.add(newstr[i].trim()); 
            }   
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
           String[] stringArr = new String[text.size()];
            text.toArray(stringArr); 
            int j=0;
            for (String a : stringArr){
            j=j+1;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        System.out.println("Новый размер = " + j);  
    }

}
```

Comment: `1)` has fewer closing `}`s than `2)`.

Comment: [Duplicate accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069403/grouping-strings-from-a-file)

Comment: The "singleibity" of the sets is founded on the equals method. Do those supposed equals elements return 0 when compared with equals()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you consider only the `{` and you do not taking into account the closing one.

Anyway this is the correct code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"))) {
            String rows[] = scan.useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("\n");
            for (String s : rows) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            String start="'";
            String end="'";

            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");

            List<StringBuilder> groups = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            //Add starting groups

            for (String line : rows) {
                if (line.trim().endsWith("{")) {
                    //group start
                    result.append(start);
                    //It is already in the new group
                    result.append(line);
                } else if (line.trim().endsWith("}")){
                    //is still with the last group
                    result.append(line);
                    //group end
                    result.append(end);
                }else{
                    result.append(line);
                }
            }
                System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

The output is correct the block are correctly identified

```
Class A{
if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
}
------------------------------------------------------------------
'Class A{'if(a>0){a=a+1:System.out.print(a);}''if(a>0){a=a+1:System.out.print(a);}'}'
```

Comment: Your decision is correct, but everything is written down in one element, and I need it to be like this:
0) 'Class A {
1) 'if (a> 0) {
a= a + 1:
System.out.print (a);
} '
2) 'if (a> 0) {
A = a + 1:
System.out.print (a);
} '
} '

Comment: you just need to remove the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `LinkedHashSet` really does remove duplicates when you use it like that.  And if it appears that it isn't doing it, then the problem is that there aren't any duplicates.

Looking at your code, I *suspect* that your problem is that the *supposed* duplicates that you are seeing are actual lines joined embedded newlines.  They are not duplicates, at the level that the `Set` sees them.

I recommend the following to confirm this:

- Use a debugger / breakpoints / single stepping to watch what is happening.
- Print the de-duped array like this:

  ```
  for (String a : stringArr){
      System.out.println("'" + a + "'");
  }
  ```

  to see if there are actually duplicate lines.  Watch where the quote characters appear!

Comment: I did as you said, it's really all different
'Class A{'
'if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}'
'if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
}'

but I want like this
'Class A{
'if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}'
'if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}'
}'

Comment: Well, then your problem is in the logic of your reassembly of lines.  I think we have answered your question about de-duping.  And I don't think I can help you with the reassembly logic problem because you have given no clear, precise explanation of the requirements for this code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking why

```
if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
```

and

```
if(a>0){
a=a+1:
System.out.print(a);
}
}
```

aren't deduplicated. It's simple: they're not the same. Note the extra `}` in the second case.

[Here's your code](http://ideone.com/VXIqvc) with some extra markings around the things printed out from the set, which should make it easier to see this.